# PHP Submitting array to POST fails

Tags: php, arrays, post

When i try to submit this simple test form to PHP:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input  name ="lang_learn[0]lang" type="text" value="1"><br>
<input  name ="lang_learn[0]level" type="text" value="2"><br>
<input  name ="lang_learn[1]lang" type="text" value="3"><br>
<input  name ="lang_learn[1]level" type="text" value="4"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

i expect to have in the $_POST array something like this:

```
Array
(
[lang_learn] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array ([lang] => 1, [level] => 2)
        [1] => Array ([lang] => 3, [level] => 4)
    )

)
```

instead i get this:

```
Array
(
[lang_learn] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 4
    )

)
```

i tried with different installations over different servers, and i always get the same result.
where is the problem? reading around this should be the right way to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The names of the input fields need fixing:

```
<input  name ="lang_learn[0][lang]" type="text" value="1"><br>
<input  name ="lang_learn[0][level]" type="text" value="2"><br>
<input  name ="lang_learn[1][lang]" type="text" value="3"><br>
<input  name ="lang_learn[1][level]" type="text" value="4"><br>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use sub-arrays, like you would in PHP.  Each key should be surrounded with `[` and `]`.  Try this...

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input  name ="lang_learn[0][lang]" type="text" value="1"><br>
<input  name ="lang_learn[0][level]" type="text" value="2"><br>
<input  name ="lang_learn[1][lang]" type="text" value="3"><br>
<input  name ="lang_learn[1][level]" type="text" value="4"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input  name ="lang_learn[0][lang]" type="text" value="1"><br>
<input  name ="lang_learn[0][level]" type="text" value="2"><br>
<input  name ="lang_learn[1][lang]" type="text" value="3"><br>
<input  name ="lang_learn[1][level]" type="text" value="4"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to do this:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input  name ="lang_learn[0][lang]" type="text" value="1"><br>
<input  name ="lang_learn[0][level]" type="text" value="2"><br>
<input  name ="lang_learn[1][lang]" type="text" value="3"><br>
<input  name ="lang_learn[1][level]" type="text" value="4"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not correct: `name ="lang_learn[0]lang"` must be `name ="lang_learn[0][lang]"`